# Removing an entry in a MySQL with Doctrine when referenced by multiple tables

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, cascade

I have a database schema where one table represents physical addresses `Addresses` and two tables representing, one representing `Manufacturers` and one representing `Vendors`.  Due to the nature of our database it is possible that a `Manufacturer` and a `Vendor` can reference the same `Address`.

My problem starts when I try to use Doctrine to remove a `Vendor` that references an `Address` that a `Manufacturer` also references.  `Manufacturer` and `Vendor` each have a `OneToOne` relationship to `Address`.

I can remove the entry just fine in phpMyAdmin, and I've tried the `cascade="remove"` and `orphanRemoval=true` option in Doctrine, but neither seem to work.

Any ideas on how to make this work?  This is how I'm defining the `address` in both `Manufacturer` and `Vendor`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $address;
```

I have no idea why I can't get this to work when it seems to work just fine in phpMyAdmin.  The relationship is uni-directional and thus `Address` has no relation to either `Manufacturer` or `Vendor`.

**EDIT** (showed code that actually is supposed to remove the entity from the database):
Here's the code that actually removed the entity (where `$instance` is just an integer that represents the `id` of the entity and `$entity` is the name of the type of entity I want to remove (e.g. `Address`):

```
//  Grab entity from Doctrine.
$entry = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository($entity)->find($instance);

//  Remove entity from database.
$this->doctrine->em->remove($entry);

//  Flush the entity manager.
$this->doctrine->em->flush();
```

The result of this code (when attempting to remove a `Vendor` instance that points to an `Address` instance that a `Manufacturer` instance also points to) is a server 500 error with the following in the error_log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`{withheld}`.`Manufacturers`, CONSTRAINT `FK_272810E7F5B7AF75` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `Addresses` (`id`))' in {withheld}/application/libraries/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:754\nStack trace:\n#0 {withheld}/application/libraries/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(754): PDOStatement->execute(Array)\n#1 {withheld}/application/libraries/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(438): Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection->executeUpdate('DELETE FROM Add...', Array)\n#2 {withheld}/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php(464): Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection->delete('Addresses', Array)\n#3 {withheld}/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(993): Doctrine\\ORM\\Persisters\\BasicEntityPersister->delete(Object(Proxies\\__CG__\\Entities\\Address))\n#4 {withheld}/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(331): Doctrine\\ORM\\UnitOfWork->executeDeletions(Object(Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\ClassMetadata))\n#5 {withheld}/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(355): Doctrine\\ORM\\UnitOfWork->commit(NULL)\n#6 {withheld}/application/controllers/ajax.php(70): Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityManager->flush()\n#7 [internal function]: Ajax->delete('vendors', '1')\n#8 {withheld}/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#9 {withheld}/index.php(202): require_once('{withheld}...')\n#10 {main}\n  thrown in {withheld}/application/libraries/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php on line 754
```

Comment: What exactly is the code you are running? What is the result?

Comment: I added your requested information.

Comment: are you sure that you're executing the same exact query? Because the failure here is quite obvious